# update set value based on another value of another column and/or same column in another row:-ORA 1427

Tags: oracle, sql-update, ora-01427

I'm trying to set a column to reset to zero or increment by +1 based on a pass or fail in another column, and/or the value of that same column in the previous weeks row.

There are two other variable columns which must match those in the previous weeks row.

Table is something like:

```
WEEK  |   ID1   |   ID2   | FLAG   | INCREMENT_COUNT  |
--------------------------------------------------------


--------------------------------------------------------
```

I have been trying to get this part of the procedure to work, and the best I've got so far is:

```
 ID_IN and ID_IN3 are passed in the procedure call
 OLD_DATE and NEW_DATE are set as the previous week and current week
----------------------------------------------------------------------         
update table1
set table1.INCREMENT_COUNT = CASE
                                 WHEN table1.FLAG is null then null
                                 WHEN table1.FLAG = 1 then 0
                                 WHEN table1.FLAG = 0 then (NVL(INCREMENT_COUNT,0)+ 1)
                                 END
where (select INCREMENT_COUNT
  from table1
  where WEEK=NEW_DATE
  and ID1=ID_IN
  and exists (select (1)
              from table2
              where table1.ID2=table2.ID2
              and table2.ID3=ID_IN3))
 =
(select INCREMENT_COUNT
  from table1
  where WEEK=OLD_DATE
  and ID1=ID_IN
  and exists (select (1)
              from table2
              where table1.ID2=table2.ID2
              and table2.ID3=ID_IN3));
```

When this procedure is called I get the error

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Additionally, in MySQL I could do it something like this and get it working...

```
update table1 as t01
left join(select ID3, ID2, INCREMENT_COUNT as prev_count from table1 as t10 inner join table2 as t2 on t10.ID2=t2.ID2 where ID1=ID_IN and ID3=ID_IN3 and t10.WEEK=OLD_DATE) as prev_date on t01.WEEK=NEW_DATE and prev_date.ID2=t01.ID2 and t01.ID1=ID_IN

set t01.INCREMENT_COUNT = if(t1.FLAG is null, null, if(t1.FLAG,0, IFNULL(prev_date.prev_count,0)+1))
where t01.ID1=ID_IN
and t1.WEEK=NEW_DATE
and prev_date.ID3=ID_IN3;
```

Comment: I'd rather expect syntax error...

Comment: yeah, I had a 'when' instead of a 'where'. But that's not related to the actual problem I'm having here.

Comment: `is` is used only for `NULL`, not for numbers. For numbers use `=`. Before the second `select` use `in` instead of `=`

Comment: Right you are. Again this is not a mistake I have in my original though. Just  a few typos .
Good point about the 'in' though. Giving it a test now.

Comment: Did you try running after changing the `=` to `in`?

Comment: Yep, just tried. Same error.

Comment: How do you want us to help you? We don't have your data, and your requirement description is very vague. Tell us the names of the tables involved, the names and data types of the columns involved (only the ones that are relevant to the problem), and the exact requirement. You want us to just look at your code and help you fix it, but you didn't post your actual code - you posted a modified version, to which you added numerous mistakes. Does that sound like a reasonable way to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Similarl to your mySQL example, you can do something like this in oracle.  This may not work for you depending on your data model.  I've put together a crude basic version based on your information, but you've not provided enough information about your data model and your tables/aliases/column names are poor for readability...

(more on update with a subquery here -> https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10008.htm#i2067871)

```
update 
    (select t01.increment_count, t01.flag, prev_date.prev_count
    from  table1 t01
    left join(select ID3, ID2, INCREMENT_COUNT as prev_count 
                from table1 t10 
              inner join table2  t2 on t10.ID2=t2.ID2     
              where ID1=ID_IN 
               and ID3=ID_IN3 
               and t10.WEEK=OLD_DATE) prev_date on t01.WEEK=NEW_DATE  and prev_date.ID2=t01.ID2 and t01.ID1=ID_IN
    where t01.ID1=ID_IN
    and t1.WEEK=NEW_DATE
    and prev_date.ID3=ID_IN3)
set INCREMENT_COUNT = if(FLAG is null, null, if(FLAG,0, IFNULL(prev_count,0)+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the queries in where condition returns more than 1 record

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd assume from that error.
The 'where' conditions could both have multiple results. I just don't know how to force it to just have one result.

Is it correct that the 'where' clause here is to define the right hand side of the 'Set'? Because that's where I need to ensure it's referring to INCREMENT_COUNT from the previous week

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have done the job.
Thanks for the help, it got me thinking in a different way.

```
 UPDATE TABLE1 T01

            SET INCREMENT_COUNT = CASE 
                                    WHEN T01.FLAG IS NULL THEN NULL
                                    WHEN T01.FLAG = 1 THEN 0
                                    WHEN T01.FLAG = 0 THEN (NVL((SELECT INCREMENT_COUNT 
                                                                        FROM TABLE1 T10
                                                                        WHERE T10.WEEK=OLD_DATE
                                                                        AND T01.WEEK=NEW_DATE
                                                                        AND T01.ID2=T10.ID2
                                                                        AND ID1=ID_IN),0)+ 1)
                                    END
            WHERE EXISTS (SELECT (1)
                      FROM TABLE2
                      WHERE TABLE1.ID2=TABLE2.ID2
                      AND TABLE2.ID3=ID_IN3);
```